# Javascript in PHP/HTML hiding Div not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to coding so be gentle.  I am building a new user interface in PHP for a database of marriage listings for use at our county library.  I am using this javascript code that was part of a solution I found here that I though I could use and modify the corresponding HTML to meet my needs:

```
    <--Javascript code-->
    function showDiv(idInfo) {
    var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

I have modified the body of the html inside the php page to attempt to provide a listing of records on the left hand side and when they select a record from the list, it displays it in the right hand side div/table that allows them to edit it in the form, then to submit after making changes.  It works well for the first couple of records you view, but on the third click it no longer hides the old records, it starts displaying additional ones in the right div.  For some reason after two successful displays, the third and any further clicks on records in the left list will just start displaying more and more records in the right side div.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the PHP/HTML:

```
    <--PHP Code-->
    <?php
    include 'config-admin-marriages.php';

    if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) { $one=$_POST['lastname']; }
    if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) { $two=$_POST['firstname']; }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM names WHERE ';

    if  (!empty($one) && !empty($two)) {
      $sql.="glast like :lastname and gfirst like :firstname or blast like :lastname and bfirst like :firstname";
    } elseif (!empty($one)) {
   $sql.="glast like :lastname or blast like :lastname";
    } else {
   $sql.="gfirst like :firstname or bfirst like :firstname"; 
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {

      if (!empty($value)) {
      $mod="$value%";
  $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $mod);
        }
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($numrows == 0) {

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="style_results.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contact">
    <h1>No results were returned from your search.</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
     } else {

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Marriage Database Modification </title>
    <link href="style_mod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modpage.js"></script>

    </head>


    <body>

    <div id="contact">
    <table border="2" width="100%">
<tr><td colspan="7"><h1>Marriage Record Modifications</h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <table border="2" width="100%">
        <div id="linkDiv">
        <tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Day</th><th>Year</th><th>Page</th><th>Source</th><th>Select</th></tr>

        <?php for ($x=0;$x < $numrows;$x++) { ?>

        <tr><td><?php echo $row[$x]['glast']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['gfirst']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['blast']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['bfirst']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['month']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['day']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['year']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['page']?></td><td><?php echo $row[$x]['id']?></td><td><input type="button" value="select" onclick="showDiv('<?php echo $row[$x]['id']?>');return false"></td></tr> <?php  }?>
        </div> 
    </table>
</td>
<td  rowspan="6" height="800px" width="1000px">

<?php for ($x=0;$x < $numrows;$x++) { ?>

<div id="divLinks">
        <div id="container<?php echo $row[$x]['id']?>" style="display:none">
    <table border="2">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <!-- The 4 container content divs. -->
        <label><?php echo $row[$x]['id']?></label>
            <form method="POST" action="showoutput.php">
                <table height="790px" width="990px">
                <tr>
              <td valign="top"><label>Groom's Last name:</label></td>
              <td><input name="glname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['glast']?>" placeholder="Last Name of Groom [Required]"/></td>
              <td valign="top"><label>Groom's First name:</label></td>
              <td><input name="gfname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['gfirst']?>" placeholder="First Name of Groom [Required]"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"><label>Bride's Last Name:</label></td>
              <td><input name="blname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['blast']?>" placeholder="Last Name of Bride [Required]"/></td>
              <td valign="top"><label>Bride's First Name:</label></td>
              <td><input name="bfname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['bfirst']?>" placeholder="First Name of Bride [Required]"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"><label>Month:</label></td>
              <td>
              <select name="mon">
                    <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['month']?>"><?php echo $row[$x]['month']?></option>
                    <option value="Jan">January</option>
                    <option value="Feb">February</option>
                        <option value="Mar">March</option>
                    <option value="Apr">April</option>
                    <option value="May">May</option>
                    <option value="Jun">June</option>
                    <option value="Jul">July</option>
                    <option value="Aug">August</option>
                    <option value="Sep">September</option>
                    <option value="Oct">October</option>
                    <option value="Nov">November</option>
                    <option value="Dec">December</option>
              </select>
              </td>
              <td valign="top"><label>Day:</label></td>
              <td><input name="da" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['day']?>"placeholder="Day number here [Required]"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"><label>Year:</label></td>
              <td><input name="yr" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['year']?>"placeholder="4 digit year i.e. 1990 [Required]"/></td>
              <td valign="top"><label>Page Number:</label></td>
              <td><input name="page" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['page']?>"placeholder="Page Number i.e. 4D [Required]"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"><label>Source:</label></td>
              <td>
              <select name="src">
                <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $row[$x]['source']?>"><?php echo $row[$x]['source']?></option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
                <option value="Greenville News">Greenville News</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="mod" value="Modify Record"></td>
               <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete Record"></td>
            </tr>
             </table>
            </form>
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </div>
   </div>
   <?php  } ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php  } ?>
```

If there is a better way, I am all ears as well.  Thanks again.  I am sorry if the code didn't format well as this is my first time using these forums.  I tried to space modify it and it didn't change in the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a revised vision of your code I did, and an example.

Condensed code using global variable:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Rja/)**

```
var lastDiv = false;

function showDiv(idInfo) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('container'+idInfo);
    if ( lastDiv ) {
        lastDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
    elm.style.display = 'block';
    lastDiv = elm;
}
```

And lastly using a loop like you had before:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78XHY/)**

```
function showDiv(idInfo) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('container'+idInfo),
    cdiv = document.getElementById("divLinks"),
    div = cdiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for( var i=0; i<div.length; i++ ) {
        div[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    elm.style.display = 'block';
}
```

This selects the target to be displayed, then loops through only the div links, making sure they are hidden before displaying the target.

Comment: I can explain this better I hope.  My result set may contain 3 records or 30 records so I loop through all records and create a table listing with the showDiv call via an onlick button which calls the corresponding div.  When showDiv('2') is selected it shows container2 with no problem.  When showDiv('3') is selected it shows container3 and hides container 2.  When showDiv('4') is selected in shows container4 but it no longer hides container 3, so both 3 and 4 are now on the screen.  If I select showDiv('5') now 3, 4 and 5 are on the screen and so on.

Comment: @Slowcoder I think I understand your issue. Updating answer.

Comment: Your code modification did the trick.  It works for every iteration of selecting records and displaying them properly.  My head thanks you and the wall I was beating it against thanks you.